# Proper way to count how many times an item from 2 lists of items are ordered together

Tags: sql, firebird

I am currently self-learning SQL so for most of you this would probably seem like a simple question (if I expressed it correctly).

I have a table 'orders' that look like this:

```
Orddid(Uid)    Ordmid      Odate        Itmsid
-----------    ------      -----        ------
  100101       100101    01.12.2018       12
  100102       100101    01.12.2018       88
  100103       100101    01.12.2018       57
  100104       100102    01.12.2018       12
```

What I want to do is count the times that any item from 2 lists of items (as in IN (itmsid1, itmsid2) coexists for all `Ordmids`.

For example, if I query about `itemsid` in (12,99) and also `itemsid` in (22,57) I would get a count of 1 at the end.

How do I do that?

EDIT: I have to say that this community is amazing! Lightning fast responses and very supportive even. Thank you very much people. I owe you!

Comment: do you mean `itemsid in (12,88)` as per your example data?

Comment: Something isn't making sense.  Is your question about 2 items or 4 items?  If about 4 items (2 lists of 2 items each), which exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Your sample data doesn't seem to match your question. Why would (22,57) result in 1? Did you mean (12,57)? Same for (12,99).

Comment: **Any** item in list A and **any** item in list B, as long as both lists have a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret your question as:

*How many times does an Ormid group feature itemid 12 or 99, in combination with itemid 22 or 57..*

Meaning, an ormid group should have either a 12 and a 22, or 12 and 57, or 99 and 22, or 99 and 27 (at least.. 12,22,57 etc would also be permitted). In plain english this might be expressed as "How many times did someone buy (a keyboard or a mouse) in combination with (a memory stick or a printer cartridge)" - to qualify for a special offer, someone has to buy at least one item from group 1, and one item from group 2

Many ways to do, here's one:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct t_or_nn.ormid) FROM

(SELECT ormid FROM orders WHERE itemid in (12,99)) t_or_nn
INNER JOIN
(SELECT ormid FROM orders WHERE itemid in (22,57)) tt_or_fs
ON t_or_nn.ormid = rr_or_fs.ormid
```

How it works:

Two subqueries; one pulls a list of all the ormids that have a 12 or 99. The other pulls a list of all the ormids that have a 22 or 57.

When these lists are joined, only the ormids that are equal will survive to become a result of the join

We thus end up with a list of only those ormids that have a 12 or 99, in combination with a 22 or 57. Counting this (distinctly, to prevent an ormid with 12,99,22 being counted as 2, or an ormid of 12,22,57,99 items being counted as 4) provides our answer.

If you need more detail on why having an ormid with itemids 12,99,22,57 results in a count of 4, let me know. I won't launch into talking about cartesian products right away as you might already know..

There are a few ways to solve things like this, I've picked on this way as it's fairly easy to explain because the query logic is fairly well aligned with the way a human might think about it

Comment: The interpretation you made is exactly what i want to do! Sorry for not managing to be more specific about it... Apart from the fact that i corrected the 'ON t_or_nn.ormid = rr_or_fs.ormid' to 'ON t1.ormid = t2.ormid' for shortening, firebird gives me this error
'Ambiguous field name between derived table T1 and derived table T2 .
ORMID.'

Comment: @PaTsuLee That is because instead of `COUNT(distinct ormid)` you need to use `COUNT(distinct t_or_nn.ormid)` **or** `COUNT(distinct tt_or_fs.ormid)`. The query has two columns `ormid`, and Firebird needs to know which one you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select o.ordmid
from orders o
where o.itmid in (12, 99)
group by o.ordmid
having count(distinct o.itmid) = 2;  -- number of items in the list
```

If items cannot repeat within an order, then use `count(o.itmid)` in the `having` rather than `count(distinct)`.

If you want the number of `ordmid`s where this occurs, then just use this as a subquery and use `count()`:

```
select count(*)
from (select o.ordmid
      from orders o
      where o.itmid in (12, 99)
      group by o.ordmid
      having count(distinct o.itmid) = 2;  -- number of items in the list
    ) o;
```

EDIT:

If you have two separate lists and you want orders that have at least one item from each list you can do:

```
select o.ordmid
from orders o
group by o.ordmid
having sum(case when o.itmid in (<list 1>) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when o.itmid in (<list 2>) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 ;
```

Comment: I think OP want just 1 in the output if condition is satisfied

Comment: I need to check if any item in 2 different lists coexist in the same order. The count should be increased only when **both** lists have at least one item that is found existing in the same ordmid

Comment: @GurwinderSingh The title says _" count how many times an item from 2 lists of items are ordered together"_

Comment: While this works, it does so only for one list of items where all items in this list are ordered together. I need to do this for at least one item in a list and another item in another list. Again, sorry if i cannot be more precise. My luck of SQL knowledge is currently limiting my ability to do so...

Comment: @PaTsuLee . . . This isn't about SQL; it is about describing clearly the problem that you have.

Answer (score 0):

You want only orders that order at least one from set1 and at least one from set 2. This means that you need to select all records where both conditions are true and then count the distinct orders:

For example, you can use `exists` to check for each order if they have a record in either set:

```
select count(distinct ordmid)
from orders o
where exists (
  select * 
  from orders 
  where ordmid = o.ordmid and itmsid in (12, 99)
)
and exists (
  select *
  from orders
  where ordmid = o.ordmid and itmsid in (22, 57)
)
```

Alternatively, you could use the quantified comparison predicate (`ANY` or `SOME`) (see also [Quantified Subquery Predicates in the Firebird 2.5 Language Reference](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-quantifiedsq)). Contrary to the `exists` solution, this removes the need for a correlated subquery.

```
select count(distinct ordmid)
from orders o
where ordmid = any(
  select ordmid 
  from orders 
  where itmsid in (12, 99)
)
and ordmid = any(
  select ordmid 
  from orders 
  where itmsid in (22, 57)
)
```